# Pandas merge columns, but not the 'key' column

Tags: python, pandas

This may seem like a stupid question, but this has been bugging me for some time.

df1:

```
imp_type    value
1           abc
2           def
3           ghi
```

df2:

```
id          value2
1           123
2           345
3           567
```

Merginge the 2 df's:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='imp_type',right_on='id')
```

yields:

```
imp_type    value    id    value2
1           abc      1     123
2           def      2     345
3           ghi      3     567
```

Then I need to drop the `id` column since it's essentially a duplicate of the imp_type column. Why does merge pull in the join key between the 2 dataframes by default? I would think there should at least be a param to set to False if you don't want to pull in the join key. Is there something like this already or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW adding `.drop("id", 1)` doesn't seem so bad to me.

Comment: I know, but it's just frustrating since it shouldn't have been implemented that way from the beginning, and to have to do it after every merge adds up and feels hacky.

Comment: As an additional example why this is bad: "id" might already exist in df1 as a column, leading to further confusion. In this case - no id column exists afterwards! (Both get renamed to id_x and id_y...)

Comment: pandas.merge(left, right, suffixes=(None, '_y') will resolve what Thomas pointed out with the _x, _y renaming. Really surprised though that the elimination of the duplicate column still has to be done outside of pandas.merge().

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I agree it would be nice if one of the columns were dropped. Of course, then there is the question of what to name the remaining column.

Anyway, here is a workaround. Simply rename one of the columns so that the joined column(s) have the same name:

```
In [23]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'imp_type':[1,2,3], 'value':['abc','def','ghi']})

In [27]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 'value2':[123,345,567]})

In [28]: df2.columns = ['imp_type','value2']

In [29]: df1.merge(df2, on='imp_type')
Out[29]: 
   imp_type value  value2
0         1   abc     123
1         2   def     345
2         3   ghi     567
```

Renaming the columns is a bit of a pain, especially (as DSM points out) compared to `.drop('id', 1)`. However, if you can arrange for the joined columns to have the same name from the very beginning, then `df1.merge(df2, on='imp_type')` would be easiest.

Comment: Good tip. Might be the best answer I get, but I'll leave this open for a bit longer in case there's other options.